# Greater than date in Axapta 2009 X++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am looking to write a query that will select all Sales Orders greater than a certain date in X++. This would be part of a job that I am writing.

Something like this:

```
SalesTable.createdDateTime > '2016-09-01'
```

I believe that I need to use `DateTimeUtil::newDateTime` to do it. I've seen examples like:

```
where salesLine.createdDateTime == DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(systemdateget(), 0)
```

How do I put an actual date in there? Or should I be using a different method? `QueryBuilder` perhaps?

Many thanks,

Anna

Comment: Hi Anna, to get actual date you can use `DateTimeUtil::getSystemDateTime()` or `DateTimeUtil::utcNow()` methods or `today()` method If you only want to date.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but how do I use that actual date in the code? I've seen various examples that has today's date - 30 (for the past month's sales orders), but what I would like to do is select all records after the 15th September (and not have that date change depending on today's date).

Comment: Try using mkdate (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa871977.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AX's query syntax or using a query object all depends on your use. Doing a date/time is useful for either.

Here is an example job that shows a more correct way to do what you want and also shows timezone considerations.

You can build a `date` object or a `utcDateTime`, which is more likely what you'll need to do.

```
static void DateTimeExample(Args _args)
{
    utcDateTime         myDateTime;
    date                myDate;
    TimeOfDay           myTimeOfDay;

    // Set your date
    myDate          = mkDate(1,10, year(today())); // Ex. October 1, 2016

    // Set time of day or just use 0
    myTimeOfDay     = DateTimeUtil::time(DateTimeUtil::utcNow());

    // Build your utcObject
    myDateTime  = DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(myDate, myTimeOfDay);

    // Apply timezone offset
    myDateTime  = DateTimeUtil::applyTimeZoneOffset(myDateTime, DateTimeUtil::getCompanyTimeZone());

    info(strFmt("utcDateTime: %1", myDateTime));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By your comment (*but how do I use that actual date in the code?)* to use this in a query you can use **this code:**

```
Query                q;
QueryRun             qr;
QueryBuildDataSource qbd;
QueryBuildRange      qbr;
utcDateTime          mutcDateTime;
date                 mDate;

;

mDate        = str2Date("15/09/2016", 123); //15h September   
mutcDateTime = DateTimeUtil::newDateTime(mDate,0);

q   = new Query();
qbd = q.addDataSource(TableNum(SalesTable));
qbr = qbd.addRange(FieldNum(SalesTable, CreatedDateTime));
qbr.value(strFmt('>%1', mutcDateTime));
qr  = new QueryRun(q);
```

To run this query by code and get `SalesTable`:

```
while(qr.next()){
    salesTable = qr.get(tablenum(SalesTable));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pradeep, Alex and Jonathan for your comments. I definitely have a lot to learn!

Comment: One last newb question, can I update those selected records while inside the while loop?

Comment: Yes of course. Before `qr  = new QueryRun(q); ` add this line `qbd.update(true);` and inside while loop in In the beginning `ttsBegin;` in the end `ttsCommit;` of course you need `SalesTable.update()` If you want you can mark this answer as correct :)

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, where do I put the ttsBegin and ttsCommit? I put them both inside the loop, but when I run the code, I get this error:                                                                                                 Cannot edit a record in Sales orders (SalesTable).
The operation cannot be completed, since the record was not selected for update. Remember TTSBEGIN/TTSCOMMIT as well as the FORUPDATE clause.

Comment: Hi Anna, all update need **TTSBEGIN, TTSCOMMIT and FORUPDATE** clause. the line `SalesTable.update` must be between `ttsBegin` and `ttsCommit`. and in this case `qbd.update(true);` replace `forUpdate` clause. Here I cannot give you an example, but you can create a new question for that!

Comment: Hi Jonathan, like you said, it works if I add salestable.selectForUpdate(true); after the ttsbegin. I had thought that using qbd.update(true); would make the table updatable, but it didn't. I'm not sure why it didn't work with only qbd.update(true);

Comment: Because AX needs to be specified to be an update in that query. If not AX inform that error. Check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa661155.aspx

Comment: Thanks Jonathan :o)